# Returning column names based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DS with 100+ columns, and need to return only column names that has rows that contains this string `'palm oil'`. I have seen some variations to this question, and have tried all combinations possible, but don't quite help me return my column names that contain rows with the string of interest. Can someone please help? This is my code below -

```
str_cols = []
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.object]).columns[7:45]:
    if df[col].str.lower().str.contains("palm", na=False):
    str_cols.append(col)
print (str_cols)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select columns based on columns names containing a specific string in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643506/select-columns-based-on-columns-names-containing-a-specific-string-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want return columns names filter columns by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `case=False` for not case sensitive:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':['palm oil',5,4,5,'palm oil 5',4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,'Palm oil',1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,'palm OIL'],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')}).astype(str)

print (df)
   A           B  C         D         E  F
0  a    palm oil  7         1         5  a
1  b           5  8         3         3  a
2  c           4  9         5         6  a
3  d           5  4  Palm oil         9  b
4  e  palm oil 5  2         1         2  b
5  f           4  3         0  palm OIL  b

m = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("palm oil", case=False, na=False)).any()

c = df.columns[m]
print (c)
Index(['B', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: OMG, I just realized my question is not very clear. What I want is names of columns returned, only if within that column it has rows that has 'palm oil'. I am truly sorry @jezrael for this mistake.

Comment: But no doubt this is very useful and i will keep it in my toolkit.

Comment: I tried this approach previously, but seeing that within my dataset I have columns that are float64 dtypes, I get an error. How can I specify to check thru only object dtypes?

Comment: then change `m = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("palm oil", case=False, na=False)).any()` to `m = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("palm oil", case=False, na=False)).any()
`

Comment: awesome, it worked! thanks for your patience @jezrael.