# Use pandas series as input parameter

Tags: python, r, pandas, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm a R user trying to pick up Python. In R, I often used vectors to pass as arguments to SQL query. For example,

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- dbGetQuery(con, paste("select * from table where ID in (", ID, ")")
```

How can I achieve this in Python? I have a dataframe and would like to use one of its columns as the parameters. So with a dataframe like this,

```
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'Value': [10,20,30,40,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[Edit]
So basically I need a string that would read "Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3,4,5)" except, instead of manually typing "1,2,3,4,5" I want to use parameters.

Comment: Would you elaborate on the  "WHERE clause of my query"?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with - selecting a column?

Comment: Does [select columns based on columns names containing a specific string in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643506/select-columns-based-on-columns-names-containing-a-specific-string-in-pandas) anser your question?

Comment: See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter) answers. To convert a pandas Series to list, use `df["ID"].tolist()`

Comment: @zabop, I edited my question, hopefully that made it clear

Comment: @Ben.T, this seems very close. But does it only work if ID is string? I get this error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found. I need the numbers to be passed as integers in the SQL query.

Comment: @Ben.T, this worked beautifully. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP are looking for something like

```
query = f"select * from table where ID in ({','.join(df['ID'].astype(str))})"
```

For more ways to create this query from `list`, one can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter) provided by @Erfan in a comment.