# BeautifulSoup Table Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this site for the starting lineups.
https://www.cbssports.com/nhl/teams/BOS/boston-bruins/depth-chart/

I am using the following code, but the table that is printed contains information I do not want, such as the player shortname and player news. I would only like to extract the CellPlayerName--long, but I am unsure how to do that.

```
url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nhl/teams/BOS/boston-bruins/depth-chart"
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find_all('table')))
df[0]
```

It prints the following:

| POS | Starter | Second | Third+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Center | P. Bergeron Bruins' Patrice Bergeron: Pots winner in NJ Patrice Bergeron Bruins' Patrice Bergeron: Pots winner in NJ | D. KrejciDavid Krejci | C. CoyleCharlie CoyleT. Nosek Bruins' Tomas Nosek: Returning Monday Undisclosed: Expected to be out until at least Jan 2 Tomas Nosek Bruins' Tomas Nosek: Returning Monday Undisclosed: Expected to be out until at least Jan 2 M. Filipe Lower Body: IR. Expected to be out until at least Jan 29 Matt Filipe Lower Body: IR. Expected to be out until at least Jan 29 |
| Left Wing | B. Marchand Bruins' Brad Marchand: Two points against Buffalo Brad Marchand Bruins' Brad Marchand: Two points against Buffalo | P. ZachaPavel Zacha | T. HallTaylor HallN. FolignoNick FolignoA. GreerA.J. Greer |
| Right Wing | J. DeBruskJake DeBrusk | D. Pastrnak Bruins' David Pastrnak: Another two-point performance David Pastrnak Bruins' David Pastrnak: Another two-point performance | T. Frederic Bruins' Trent Frederic: Scores goal Wednesday Trent Frederic Bruins' Trent Frederic: Scores goal Wednesday C. SmithCraig Smith |
| Left Defenseman | H. LindholmHampus Lindholm | M. GrzelcykMatt Grzelcyk | D. ForbortDerek ForbortJ. ZborilJakub Zboril |
| Right Defenseman | C. McAvoyCharlie McAvoy | B. CarloBrandon Carlo | C. CliftonConnor Clifton |
| Goalie | L. Ullmark Bruins' Linus Ullmark: Staring in Winter Classic Linus Ullmark Bruins' Linus Ullmark: Staring in Winter Classic | J. Swayman Bruins' Jeremy Swayman: Falls short in OT Jeremy Swayman Bruins' Jeremy Swayman: Falls short in OT | — |

Edit:
This is the desired output

| POS | Starter | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Center | Patrice Bergeron | David Krejci | Charlie Coyle Tomas Nosek Matt Filipe |
| Left Wing | Brad Marchand | Pavel Zacha | Taylor Hall Nick Foligno A.J. Greer |
| Right Wing | Jake DeBrusk | David Pastrnak | Trent Frederic Craig Smith |
| Left Defenseman | Hampus Lindholm | Matt Grzelcyk | Derek Forbort Jakub Zboril |
| Right Defenseman | Charlie McAvoy | Brandon Carlo | Connor Clifton |
| Goalie | Linus Ullmark | Jeremy Swayman |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe) and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643506/select-columns-based-on-columns-names-containing-a-specific-string-in-pandas

Comment: @JonSG Definitely not the correct duplicate; the DF is created with the correct columns but there is superfluous information *within* the cells themselves that the OP is looking to remove.

Comment: I’m on mobile so limited opportunity for me to formulate a complete answer for a bit but this should be possible to do by modifying the loaded HTML document up front with the BS4 instance you already have

Comment: @esqew "player short name" and "player news" and "player name - long" all look like column names to me.  None appearing in the given output so it looks to me like the OP wants to drop a column or perhaps select a column.

Comment: I have edited the initial question to include the desired output as it looks like it was confusing people. I do not want to drop a column, I want to eliminate the superfluous information as esqew mentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some text present in cell `<td>` but is not displayed, because, that is hidden using CSS (and varies depending on device - my obsevation). The expected result can be obtained by removing extra information from the table.

The code should be like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nhl/teams/BOS/boston-bruins/depth-chart"
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# remove the colgroup
soup.find('colgroup').decompose()   # remove the colgroup 


# remove the class 'CellPlayerName--short', because they are needed in output
short = soup.find_all('span', class_='CellPlayerName--short')
for s in short:
    s.decompose()



# Also delete class name 'CellPlayerName-icon'
icon = soup.find_all('span', class_='CellPlayerName-icon')
for i in icon:
    i.decompose()

# You can also add the code to remove the cell if it contains only ' - '

df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find_all('table')))
print(df[0])
```

### Output:

| POS | Starter | Second | Third+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Center | Patrice Bergeron | David Krejci | Charlie CoyleTomas NosekMatt Filipe |
| Left Wing | Brad Marchand | Pavel Zacha | Taylor HallNick FolignoA.J. Greer |
| Right Wing | Jake DeBrusk | David Pastrnak | Trent FredericCraig Smith |
| Left Defenseman | Hampus Lindholm | Matt Grzelcyk | Derek ForbortJakub Zboril |
| Right Defenseman | Charlie McAvoy | Brandon Carlo | Connor Clifton |
| Goalie | Linus Ullmark | Jeremy Swayman | — |

#### Edit 1:

Included the removal the text of class `CellPlayerName-icon`.